# Binary Conversion in c++

Tags: c++, binary

In order to convert a given number to binary I wrote this code

```
//Binary conversion

int num,count=0;

int bi[15];
cout<<"Enter number";
cin>>num;
while(num>=1){
    bi[count]=num%2;
    num=num/2;
    count++;
}


for(int i=0;i<=count;i++){
    cout<<bi[count-i];
}
```

But the answer is wrong.It gives a -85993460 at the front.

If I want to convert 10 the result would be -859934601010.

Can someone please point out what's wrong with this code

Comment: @Lashane Sure about the `i<=count`?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ no, should be just `<`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `i` is zero, the expression `count-i` is one position after the last entry of the array; this is undefined behavior, so an arbitrary number, such as -85993460, can be printed, or the program could crash.

To print your array backwards, use `bi[count-1-i]` instead, and end the loop upon reaching count:

```
for(int i=0 ; i != count ; i++) {
    cout<<bi[count-1-i];
}
```

Comment: Thanks.When I tried to find the error I checked the code until num=1 , but then forgot to increment the count.That's why I couldn't find the error.

Answer (score 1):

Your loop limits are off-by-one - the loop should be

```
for(int i=1;i<=count;i++){
    cout<<bi[count-i];
}
```